# How do I manipulate the default header when creating an asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I am creating a web application using Visual Studio 2015. As per my school instructions, I am using asp.net web forms (with master page in this case).

Before I even get into the actual design and functionality of the web application, the two things I wanted to setup was a bootstrap theme/layout (which I have successfully managed) and also a site wide header and footer.

This is where I am having issues. The application has a default header (a dark bar across the top with saying "Application name" and links "Home ... About ... Contact" and  login/register links on the far right. The default footer is a simple "© 2016 - My ASP.NET Application"

My question is where do I go to change these? I want to change the link names, change where the links take you to and remove the login/register links altogether.

I'm really sorry if i'm being completely stupid, I have only previously used Netbeans to write a Java application, meaning this is my first time using C#, ASP.NET and Visual Studio.

Comment: These are usually in a master page.

Comment: When I create the project, the only pages that are there are: default, about & contact. And I can't access the header or footer in any of these. I can't see any master page? Again, apologies if i'm coming across dim :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout information is usually in a master page in a Web Forms project. By default with a new Web Forms site created with Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, this file is Site.Master.

[image: image showing Visual Studio default Web Forms template]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! The only other thing now is, can you tell me why the Home/About/Contact links are in the source but not in the design?

Comment: @ACostea Because designers can't handle all the intricacies of an interactive webpage. *Do not use a designer*. Just hand edit the HTML.

Comment: The reason for this is that my professor told us that we would be using next to no HTML for this project and it can all be done with drag and drop/c#. I wanted to be able to just delete the links from the design and add my own with the designer? Thanks again :)

Comment: Ah ok, i'll look into what I need to edit in the HTML code, thanks!

Comment: @ACostea You do not drag and drop with C#. You can drag/drop with an HTML designer, but again, the result will be atrocious. Your professor is doing you a huge disfavor if they say to use a designer. My advice is ignore it, and learn HTML and CSS. You'll get better results.

Answer (score 0):

If we take into account a web site setup in Visual Studio 2015 then, In the Solution Explorer, open the master page (probably named Site.master) or if unsure then see the default.aspx page source where you can check the name of the master page in the first line or Page Directive (starts with <%@ Page ...) with attribute "MasterPageFile=....".

In the master page, You should find the the following div with the classes assigned

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

Inside this div is all the html for the top header bar and you can change the names and url of links and the headings in there.

Hope this helps.